# java - register problem

Tags: java

When i try to register a person with the name Eric for example, and then again registrating Eric it works. This should not happen with the code i have. Eric should not be registrated if theres already an Eric in the list. Here is my full code:

```
     private Person findName(String name) {
        for (Person person : personer) {
            if (person.getName() == name) {
                return person;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }





 private boolean containsName(String name) {

       return findName(name) != null;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
if (person.getName() == name)
```

You want

```
if (person.getName().equals(name))
```

In Java, "==" is *reference equality* for non-primitive types. The reference to `name` (i.e., its "address", if you will) isn't the same as the reference to the object returned by `getName()`.

See also: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221

Comment: +1 for getting the part of the code that's wrong. However, the code's design is wrong too (see my post), and after fixing _that_, there is no manual comparisons of names any more, so this problem doesn't crop up.

Comment: I tend to be wary of opening up that can of worms here, but you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

Brian's answer is correct. However, on a "forest instead of trees" level, the code's design needs to be fixed too:

If you want a collection of sorted names, and be able to search for existing names, you should be using a `TreeMap`. An `ArrayList` (that you sort on each insertion, no less) is totally the wrong data structure for this.

Comment: Or a `TreeSet`. Or even a `HashSet`. Of course, if you're only ever going to have five users or so, it doesn't matter all that much...

Comment: @Brian: +1 Yes, you're right, `TreeSet` is good too, though by using a map keyed by the name you can just use natural ordering and not have to write a custom comparator. (`HashSet` is fine in the general case, but here the OP wants the items sorted by name.)